# Where can we get demographic data by zip code for USA?

Tags: dataset, demographics

I am looking for demographics data such as Population, Gender, Race, Housing, Employment Status and also it needs to be by zip code for USA.
Any idea where i could easily download it ?

Comment: For more datasets, I would suggest posting on https://opendata.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5):

The [Census Bureau American FactFinder](https://factfinder.census.gov/faces/nav/jsf/pages/community_facts.xhtml) is a free source of comprehensive and detailed data. Unfortunately, it’s not particularly easy to use in its raw format.

We’ve pulled, cleaned, consolidated, and reformatted the Census Bureau data. The details of this process and how to use the data files can be found on our [team blog](https://medium.com/ro-data-team-blog/census-demographic-data-by-zip-code-f2f47c87655).

None of these tables actually have a field called “ZIP code.” Rather, they have a field called “ZCTA5”. A ZCTA5 (or ZCTA) can be thought of as interchangeable with a zip code given following caveats:

- There are no ZCTAs for PO Box ZIP codes - this means that for 42,000 US ZIP Codes there are 32,000 ZCTAs.
- ZCTAs, which stand for Zip Code Tabulation Areas, are based on zip codes but don’t necessarily follow exact zip code boundaries. If you would like to read more about ZCTAs, please refer to [this link](https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/zctas.html). The Census Bureau also provides an [animation](https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/zcta/zcta_delin_anim.html) that shows how ZCTAs are formed.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from here - https://www.nhgis.org/

Signup and choose the topic - eg: Age, Household, etc.,
they also have spatial files.